# About using fix-points to define partial recursive functions

Tags: logic, computability

In untyped lambda calculus, the fix-point operator $\mathcal{Y}$ can be used "to create" recursion. This is ok to me. But when we think about fix-points in the context of recursive functions, although we have a similar theorem that presents fix-points, this fix-points operates only on indices of recursion functions. The theorem says that, given a total function $f$, there is a fix point $n$ such that $\phi_n = \phi_{f(n)}$. In Odifreedi book, Classical Recursion Theory, page 157, it says we can take only this components to define all the partial recursive functions:

[image]

I didn't get what are this fixed-point definitions. How we can understand this? It seems to me if we take only the fix-point theorem as a way to define other functions, we would get stuck in the indices. For example, if $f$ is the function $f(x) = xf(x-1)$, if $x \not = 0$, and $f(x) = 1$, if $x= 0$, we would get:

$$\phi_n \simeq  \phi_{f(n)} \simeq \phi_{f\circ f(n)} \simeq ... \simeq \phi_{n!}$$

But it seems to me we would have to use the S-m-n theorem to get the $n!$ out of the indices. In wikipedia (link [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kleene%27s_recursion_theorem)) it says we have to use the second recursion theorem to get this (and the second recursion theorem needs the S-m-n plus fix-point theorems). The second theorem says that, for every partial recursive functions $\psi$, there is a index $e$ such that:

$$\phi_e(x) \simeq \psi(e,x).$$
This theorem uses the S-m-n theorem in the proof. And it seems it can be used to get a function $\psi$ out of the index. But I didn't understand the proof used in wikipedia to show that we can eliminate primitive recursion in this context.

So my questions are:

1. How this proof works?
2. What are "fixed-point definitions"? Can we assume it is only the fix-point theorem? Or we need something like the S-m-n theorem also (or the second recursion theorem)?

Comment: Odifreddi explains what he means by fixed point definitions just above the statement of the theorem. I think the concept of (an) index of a partial recursive function in that explanation is intended to refer to the discussion after the original definition of "partial recursive function".

Comment: Which is exactly the proof you are asking about and what is that you don't understand in that proof? Also, what is the problem if you use the smn-theorem in the proof of second recursion theorem?